# How to make a physics simulation permanent

Tags: physics

I have a bed of pebbles that have been physics simulated and are now in a resting position:

[image: pebble bed]

I want to append this to an architectural render I'm working on. When appending, the pebbles go back to their start position (suspended in space).

I don't want to bake the simulation, because it's only the ending position I care about. Is there a way to apply all the pebble's positions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create you RigidBody simulation
2. Choose the desire frame
3. Select your objects,
4. perform `Bake to Keyframes` (hit F3 for the search menu and type bake)
5. Change the frame range to the frame selected. If you leave the default, i.e. multiple frames, it create keyframes for all.

**ALTERNATIVE**:

1. step to the desired frame,
2. `Apply Visual Transform` followed by
3. either `Remove Rigid Bodies` or `Remove Rigid Body World`

[image]
[image]

Comment: The menu item *Bake to Keyframes* does not appear when I search (prob because I had already baked, which doesn't work when linking across files). Nevertheless, you gave me the idea to try *Remove Rigidbody World* (at the desired keyframe), and it worked!
If you edit your answer to explain how to get the menu item, or amend it to include my solution, I'll be glad to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Roger that thank you

Comment: That said, removing the RigidBody World did not work for me. Even after baking the cache. It simply reverts to the original position.

Comment: After a few tests, I can confirm that stepping to the desired location and doing *Apply Visual Transform* followed by either *Remove Rigid Bodies* or *Remove Rigid Body World* will work.

Answer (score 3):

First off, go to the target frame and make sure only your pebbles are selected.

In the *3D Viewport*, under *Object* > *Rigid Body* select *Apply Transformation*. This will make the current position the pebbles' starting one.

[image]

Then, in the same submenu, click *Remove* to remove the pebbles from the Rigid Body simulations; that is, to make them simple, static meshes again.

Comment: I did try this solution, but the frames are animated as before. Will this work with clones of objects (all my pebbles are three different copies that share the same mesh and material)?

Comment: I'm conflicted, because when I tried your answer, the *Remove* option did not appear. However, in a new file, it does, and your solution works. So, you solution did not solve my problem, but it does work. However, because of everyone's input, I was able to find a way, so I'm marking this one as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Select the object and press `CTRL + A > Apply visual transform`

Comment: Tried your solution, and it says that because my objects are multi-user, transforms cannot be applied (for *all transforms*). *Apply visual transform* does nothing in my case.

Comment: Are you sure you actually select **Apply Visual Transform** and not any other apply option?

Comment: I believe you are correct. *Apply Object Transform* doesn't work, but *Apply Visual Transform* does (though it doesn't help). However, your solution does work if followed by *Remove Rigid Bodies*.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the simulation
2. step to the desired frame
3. In the 3D Viewport, under Object > convert to > Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text

This create the copy from the simulation

Comment: (Blender 2.92) Make sure to select "keep original" after step 3 in the pop-up dialog in the 3d viewport if you want to retain a copy of your objects with simulation applied.