# Apply transformations after animation

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes

I've created a wall with the extras *Wall Factory* add-on. My intentions are to just break that wall into small pieces, and for it I use the *Cell Fracture* add-on.

What I'd like to achieve is just create the cells, break the object and when I find a suitable spot for me, apply all the animation so it's static and applied to the mesh now (like, even though I move through frames, they will stay the same so I can proceed to apply different animations to different objects).

**Steps I've followed:**

1. Create wall with Wall Factory
2. Apply Cell Fracture
3. Select all pieces and add "Rigid body: Active" (*Object > Rigid Body > Add Active*)
4. Put some objects in the scene, and add "Rigid body: Passive" to them (*Object > Rigid Body > Add Passive*)
5. Press `Space` key and, when I find it ok, press again to pause animation

The issue is I cannot even move any piece (part of the broken wall) because it won't respond to movement, so I cannot make little adjustments or use them as boolean or whatever, and if I apply transformations (`Ctrl+A`) all of the pieces then are moved and spread everywhere across the viewport (sometimes), and even in this state **they still go back to their original position if I slide the timeline frame**.

I've tried to apply transformations before and after the animation takes place, but I cannot seem to find a way to **achieve the pieces to make their final position a static one, so no matter what further modifications are done in the timeline, they will mantain their transforms in place**.

Thank you.

Comment: We are missing a crucial piece of information: How are you animating the pieces? If they are rigid body simulations then you can apply it in the modifier tab. If they aren't, are you manually adding keyframes? As far as I know the Cell Fracture Addon Only fractures the mesh and doesn't apply animations to the result.

Comment: I've edited my question so that this information is added. Thank you @IAmGettingTiredOfAliases!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that applying [this solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173069/how-to-make-a-physics-simulation-permanent) will work. However, I had to make a global collection for all my pieces (as I had multiple separated walls breaking), so I could make `Select Objects` from all the pieces and could remove Rigid Body (Object > Rigid Body > Remove) from all at once. Otherwise, only one of the walls would remain and the others would disappear (I don't know if this is an expected behavior).

To sum up:

1. Select all your pieces in the desired frame (I've done so by grouping them all in a collection, and then *Right Click > Select objects*)
2. Press `Ctrl + A+` and select *Visual transform*
3. With all the pieces still selected, go to *Object > Rigid Body > Remove*

Now pieces can be moved and no matter what frame you go back to, they will remain the same without alterations.